# Update database without reloading page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Ive just had some fantastic help from Sandeepan, thank you!

Please can anyone see what I have done wrong with this ....

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javasript">

function addItemToUsersList(itemId)
{
  $.ajax({
      'url': 'member-bucketadd-execTEST.php', 
       'type': 'GET',
      'dataType': 'json', 
      'data': {itemid: itemId}, 
       'success': function(data) 
       {
           if(data.status)
           {
               if(data.added)
                {
                        $("span#success"+itemId).attr("innerHTML","Item added to your personal list");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                        $("span#success"+itemId).attr("innerHTML","This item is already on your list");
                }
            }
       },
       beforeSend: function() 
         {
               $("span#success"+itemId).attr("innerHTML","Adding item to your bucketlist...");
         }
          'error': function(data) 
          {
          // what happens if the request fails.
            $("span#success"+itemId).attr("innerHTML","An error occureed");
        }
});
                  }
     </script>

</head>
```

Then the button to activate the function in :

```
   <a onclick='addItemToUsersList("<?php echo $itemid ; ?>")'> Add<img src='images/plus-green.png' /> </a>
```

and the exec page:

```
<?php 

if($bucketlist < 1) 
 {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO membersbuckets (memberbucketid, userid, bucketid, complete)
    VALUES ('', '$userid', '$_GET['itemId]', '0')");
        return json_encode(array("status" => true, "added" => true));
 }
 else
 {
        return json_encode(array("status" => true, "added" => false));
 }



//echo "You are being directed to your bucket list, please wait a few moments...<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='2; URL=mybucketlist.php'/>";
?>
```

The links are showing up as links but nothing happens when I click them!! Here is the test page I am working on http://olbl.co.uk/showbucketsTEST.php
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
<a onclick="addItemToUsersList("<?php echo $itemid ; ?>")">
```

into

```
<a onclick="addItemToUsersList(<?php echo $itemid ; ?>)">
```

(quotes inside quotes are causing a problem.)

**EDIT:** Also, change:

```
<script type="text/javasript">
```

into

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

As suggested by @Dave, I traced the problem with firebug, and it said `addItemToUsersList` is not defined, so I searched for it in the content and found the typo in the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thanks aularon I tried removing hte quotes but, still the same thing, its not activating the link??

Comment: oops! Thanks. I downloaded firebug as dave said and kept clicking stuff till i saw some errors in the bottom right corner! and i can see the additemtouserslist is not defined. I have changed the sript to script, taken out the quotes yet its still undefined. Am i missing some quotes anywhere round here - at the funtion add... bit?
<script type="text/javascript">
function addItemToUsersList(itemId)
{
  $.ajax({
      'url': 'member-bucketadd-execTEST.php', 
       'type': 'GET',
      'dataType': 'json', 
      'data': {itemid: itemId}, 
       'success': function............

Comment: sorry, bit jumbled:
this bit
<script type="text/javascript"> function addItemToUsersList(itemId)

Comment: @Dan you have a missing comma, just before `'error': function(data)`, I could tell from firebug error message at the console, then I copied your code and tried executing it at the console (you can have a larger console with the arrow, execute then with `CTRL+ENTER`), I kept changing the code to figure out where's the missing part, till I found it, it didn't take much time though, thanks to firebug : ) (Thanks again @Dave for reminding us to not only tell the solution but how to get to it)

Comment: I will have a look at the console thing, javascript and ajax is something that I have never played with so this is all new. Thank you for the solution! and also for firebug! You guys n gals are great!! :)

Comment: You are welcome anytime : ) we are happy we helped you find some resources to help you debug and do stuff. BTW, don't forget to choose accepted answers for your questions.

Comment: Ahh, didn't realise! Done. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I'd figure it out. Open the page in Firefox with Firebug turned on. Turn on the "console."

If it's a Javascript error you'll see it. Firebug displays ajax traffic too so you can open your ajax requests and see if you got a server error.

Comment: This should be a comment, this is not an answer (I agree it's the way to solve this issue, though).

Comment: Never used firebug, downloaded and attempting to work it out now ;)

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, you must have an 'href' attribute for the browser to recognize this as a link.  Try adding `href="javascript:void(0)"` to the links.  A `#` would make the page refresh.

UPDATE: Hmm, this is true about not being a 'link' but with jQuery the event should fire regardless.  I'd still try it.

Comment: yes, you are correct. this i forgot, then remembered.  thx Dave